# Object is not aiming correctly when player flips

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

The localScale of my weapon does not flip when my player and weapon holder (the parent) flip. This is the code currently, the weapon is set to always aim at the mouse but it does not do so when it is flipped

```
    //Get Mouse Position
    worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
    _direction = (worldPos - (Vector2)weapon.transform.parent.position).normalized;
    weapon.transform.parent.right = _direction;

    //Flip when aiming back
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(_direction.y, _direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    Vector3 localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    if (angle > 90 || angle < -90)
    {
        localScale.y = -1f;
    }
    else
    {
        localScale.x = 1f;
    }

    weapon.transform.localScale = localScale;
```

I tried manually adjusting the weapons localScale but that made it either be upside down or still not face the mouse

```
    //Get Mouse Position
    worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
    _direction = (worldPos - (Vector2)weapon.transform.parent.position).normalized;
    weapon.transform.parent.right = _direction;

    //Flip when aiming back
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(_direction.y, _direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    Vector3 localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    if (angle > 90 || angle < -90)
    {
        localScale.x = -1f;
        localScale.y = -1f;
    }
    else
    {
        localScale.x = 1f;
        localScale.y = 1f;
    }

    weapon.transform.localScale = localScale;
```

Comment: `if (angle > 90 || angle < -90)
    {
        localScale.y = -1f;
    }
    else
    {
        localScale.x = 1f;
    }` looks odd .. why is one using `y` and he other case `x` ?

Comment: i was just trying anything to see any kind of fix